# How to parse the full content of a XML element to object in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have some kind of complex XML data structure. The structure contains different fragments like in the following example:

```
<data>
   <content>
     <h1>Hello <strong>World</strong>. This is some text.</h1>
   </content>
   <content2>.....</content2>
  ....
</data>
```

Java Object looks like,

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class Data
{
  @XmlElement(name = "content")
  private Content content;
  
  @XmlElement(name = "content2")
  private Content2 content2;
}


@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "content")
public class Content
{
  @XmlElement(name = "h1")
  private H1 h1;
 
}

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "h1")
public class H1
{
  @XmlPath("text()")
  private String text;

  @XmlElement(name = "strong")
  private String strong;
  
}
```

But I'm getting the value for h1 -> text as "Hello" but I want full text values either

> "Hello . This is some text."

or

> "Hello World. This is some text."

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you have embedded HTML inside your XML. This means your XML is now most likely malformed and parsing it won't work. If you are lucky you might be able to get something out but your code will remain unreliable. You will have to fix your input data first. If it turns out you do have valid XML that happens to use HTML like tags then you should be able to walk the DOM tree of the h1 tag and spit out all text as you go along.

Comment: It looks like this above document is wellformed. Just because you think it is HTML does not make the document malformed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you perceive is working by design.

Your H1 class has the elements text and strong. The parser is instructed to populate H1.text with the text() content of H1, which per definition is the concatenation of all text parts on that level. Even with the strong field filled, you lost the information where in the original text strong was found.

I believe it might be better for you to define content as DOM XML data (not sure how it is done with the annotations you use) so at some later time and if need be you can serialize it back to the original string.